# mail_room with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't seem to get mail_room working in a Rails app.
When testing the logger delivery method, it works correctly with this

config/mail_room.yml

```
---
:mailboxes:
  -
    :email: "some@gmail.com"
    :password: "password"
    :name: "inbox"
    :delivery_method: logger
    :log_path: "email.log"
```

but the postback delivery method doesn't seem to work at all

config/mail_room.yml

```
---
:mailboxes:
  -
    :email: "some@gmail.com"
    :password: "password"
    :name: "inbox"
    :delivery_method: postback
    :delivery_url: "http://global-or-local-ip/inbox"
    :delivery_token: "abcdefg"
```

config/routes.rb

```
post 'inbox', :to => 'users#inbox', :as => :users_inbox
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def inbox
        puts "Check your inbox..."
    end
end
```

Not sure if it's because of mail_room or something missing from the Rails app. I've tried different verbs in the routes. Using Rails 4.0.2 and tried both 0.1.0 and github source for the gem.

Comment: First it should be `POST` as it says in the documentation of the gem.
What is the error that you get?

Comment: Hi. I've tried POST and every other verb as stated at the end but I'll edit that in now. Sorry for the confusion. I'm not getting any errors. It just doesn't hit the method as expected.

Comment: My first guess is that it might be denying it due to request forgery protection. You could try turning off `protect_from_forgery` entirely, or just `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:inbox]` inside your `UsersController`.

Comment: Tried both but nothing seems to happen. There's nothing in the console/log to suggest that it's even being hit with a POST request.

Comment: We've started an issue on the project: https://github.com/tpitale/mail_room/issues/8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, we found that Faraday 0.8.8 was having some issues with ruby 2.0 as we were using it in mail_room. Released a new gem, and made notes in the README that users should install >= 0.8.9 of Faraday.